# Implementing ShowDialog which is work in the same thread

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog

I am developing a WPF application and i want to show Dialogs in the active Window using a PopUp or a Different grid (by changing ZIndex in this grid).

currently my solution works using Event and Event Handlers:

```
 public static void ShowDialog(IDialog DialogControl)
 {
     // Get Active Window ...
     CurrentWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsActive);
     CurrentContent = (UIElement)CurrentWindow.Content;
     CurrentWindow.Content = null;
     CurrentContent.IsEnabled = false;     

     Grid DialogGrid = new Grid();
     Panel.SetZIndex(DialogGrid, 1);
     // ... 
     var Dialog = DialogControl.GetUserControl();

     DialogGrid.Children.Add(Dialog);

     DialogControl.OnDialogComplete += (object sender, DialogResult result) => { RestoreWindow(); OnDialogComplete?.Invoke(sender, result); };

     CurrentWindow.Content = DialogGrid;
 }

 interface IDialog
 {
     UserControl GetUserControl();
     event DialogComplete OnDialogComplete;
 }
```

So, I'm using it in this way :

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     DialogCenter.OnDialogComplete += DialogCenter_OnDialogComplete;
     DialogCenter.ShowDialog(new Test());
 }

 private void DialogCenter_OnDialogComplete(object sender, DialogResult result)
 {
     // Take Result and Do something 
     DialogCenter.OnDialogComplete -= DialogCenter_OnDialogComplete;
 }
```

this is a ugly code and i don't want to make my codes more Complicated.
i have tried to wait for DialogResult but this Dialog is in the same thread and waiting will blocks my execution.

is there any way to do this work in a cleaner way ?

Comment: What's wrong with `someWindow.ShowDialog()`.  It's not clear what your intention is

Comment: I want to Implement something like Bootstrap Modals : https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: Just use `ShowDialog`.  Web development are foreever re-inventing the wheel

Comment: Ripping out the `Content` of an existing window and replacing it with something else could lead to unexpected results with MVVM bindings.  You are using MVVM with your WPF app?  Why pretend to emulate z-order?  WPF isn't a JavaScript domain.  WPF is more than capable of displaying real controls with real z-order  Anyway, you may want to ask this over at _Code Review Stack Exchange_.  Be sure to read the FAQ first.  good luck

Comment: Thanks `MickyD`, I'm newbie in WPF world. I'm not using MVVM at this time, because i haven't a good sense in this architecture, i have created my UserControls and i have some binding (in ControlTemplate re-writings). Actually I have tried MaterialDesignXaml (https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit) there were some Control to show Dialogs in this library but they were not stable, Sometimes i couldn't close dialogs and it was a serious problem for me (it was designed in MVVM) . i have tried to move into C# Codes because i thought it's safer for me to get involve.

Comment: You mean that i show my dialogs in a new Window (Like MessageBox, FileDialogs, ...) ? I have tried to add a window into another one but it just runs into a runtime error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176479/discussion-between-rezanoei-and-mickyd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this very nicely by making use of the `async`/`await` keywords and `TaskCompletionSource<T>`.

```
public static Task<DialogResult> ShowDialogAsync(IDialog DialogControl)
{
    //setup code ...

    var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<DialogResult>();

    DialogControl.OnDialogComplete += (object sender, DialogResult result) => 
    { 
        RestoreWindow();
        taskCompletionSource.SetResult(result); 
    };

    CurrentWindow.Content = DialogGrid;

    return taskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

An then you can call it like this:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = await DialogCenter.ShowDialogAsync(new Test());
    //do stuff (dialog is completed at this point)
}
```

You may notice the `async void` which is commonly considered bad practice; however, the main exception to that general rule is for event handlers, which is exactly how we are using it.

Comment: OP: _"i don't want to make my codes `more` Complicated"_.  What exactly does `async` bring to the table here?   Plain anonymous methods might have been simpler

Comment: It makes the calling code less complicated. The calling code will look just like if you were to call `Window.ShowDialog()` with the addition of one 5 letter keyword (`await`), and the advantage of not blocking the UI thread. There's no longer the need to create a separate event handler and register it and unregister it everytime you want to call the dialog.

Comment: 1) `async` is immediately more complicated than single threading and you've made the caller more complex 2) `await` requires the caller's method signature to change to include `async` 3) modal dialogs are supposed to block the rest of the UI 4) there is no reason the OP could not have simply chosen to use an _anonymous method_ instead of a callback 5) though you have cut down on a method (which as I said the OP could do as well quite easily) you've made the app more complex, something the OP didn't want.  `shorter does not mean less complex`

Comment: 1) If `async` made things immediately more complicated, it would not be useful and would have never been implemented be the C# language designers. Tasks are not threads, and nothing about the single threaded nature has changed at all. 2) The addition of `async` keyword does not change the method signature. 3) There are plenty of easy ways to block the rest of the UI if that is desired/necessary.

Comment: 4) `async` accomplishes exactly the same thing as anonymous methods with out actually having to explicitly declare them (the code can look like regular procedural code and behind the scenes the C# compiler is automatically turning it into delegates for you, with the added benefit of things like try/catch/finally just working like normal, which is not the case for delegates) 5) that is simply your opinion

Comment: Dave M, I have tried your codes, but they will block my UI, the problem is the Threading behind the task. my Window and my Dialog are in the same Thread.

Comment: No, if implemented properly, it won’t block the UI. Tasks are not threads. They are a higher level abstraction. I use this pattern all the time in various ways to implement non-UI-blocking operations.

Comment: The only difference between what you said and what i have done is `public static async Task<DialogResult> ShowDialog` in method signature and `return taskCompletionSource.Task.Result` at the end of the method.

Comment: That’s the problem, don’t declare the method async and don’t return taskCompletionSource.Task.Result. Just return taskCompletionSource.Task

Comment: I have updated the answer with the exactly correct code

Comment: Doing .Result forces a synchronous wait for the Task to be completed. Our goal is to return an uncompleted Task that will complete later

Comment: Either don’t mark the method as async or return await taskCompletionSource.Task